# How to compute the operator norm for the following linear operator?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

I have  a linear operator $T:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $T\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}.$ The domain and codomain spaces are having Euclidean norms on them. Then what is the norm of $T.$ The definition for a norm here is $\|T\|=sup \Big\{\frac{\|Tv\|_2}{\|v\|_2} \hspace{0.05 cm}:v\neq 0\Big\}$

Comment: It is $\sqrt2$.

Comment: How to compute?

Comment: First you need the correct definition, it is a $\sup$ rather than $\inf$.  Then there are many possible methods, and which you might want to use depends on context that is absent.  Maybe just try computing $\|Tv\|/\|v\|$ in generic form and see how you can bound it?

Comment: Yes you are right.. its supremum. Then if it is supremum how to calculate?

Comment: Do you mean it is 2-norm of a matrix i.e $\|T\|=\sqrt{a}$ where $a=$maximum eigen value of $T^*T$

Comment: That is true, but I don't know if I meant it. In this case TT* is easier.